# Please Suggest Qt based open source games?

Tags: qt

I am comfortable with Qt and want to learn game programming.
Can you please suggest Qt based open source games (I will read source code of it)?

Comment: Here is the best link http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Qt_Based_Games

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all [kde games](http://www.kde.org/applications/games/). But they might written with the support of KDE specific libraries, not vanilla Qt.

  - e.g. [knetwalk](http://www.kde.org/applications/games/knetwalk/)
  - or [bomber](http://www.kde.org/applications/games/bomber/)
- [qgo](http://qgo.sourceforge.net/)
- [here is a list](http://qt-apps.org/index.php?xcontentmode=4250x4251x4252x4253x4254)
- [another list](http://kde-apps.org/index.php?xcontentmode=250x251x252x253x254)

Comment: I want to learn basics of physics, can you suggest a game for that ( I will read code of it)?.

Comment: Mh, I don't know. Perhaps grabbing a book on physics / game programming would be better than reading physics code.

Comment: Here is the best link http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Qt_Based_Games